# Calculating Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \text{Abuse} & \text{Neglect} & \text{Nonabuse Control} \\ \hline \overline{y}_1 = 81.06 & \overline{y}_2 = 78.56 & \overline{y}_3 = 87.81\\ \hline s_1 = 17.05 & s_2 = 15.43 & s_3 = 14.36\\ \hline n_1 = 32 & n_2 = 16 & n_3 = 16\\\hline\end{array}$$

> Calculate simultaneous confidence intervals for the differences.

So I think this is the formula I should be using:

$$\overline{y}_{j}-\overline{y}_{j'}\pm t_{\alpha/2m}\cdot s\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_j}+\frac{1}{n_{j'}}}$$

I think the degrees of freedom would be $n-k=64-3=61$, $m =3$ since there are are $3\choose{2}$$=3$ ways to choose $2$ out of the $3$ groups.

However, how could I calculate $s$? I am reading that $s=\sqrt{\text{MSE}}$ but it looks like I need individual data values to calculate the MSE. Should I use

$$s_{\text{pooled}}=\sqrt{\frac{(n_j-1)s_j^2+(n_{j'}-1)s_{j'}^2}{n_j+n_{j'}-2}}$$

If this is all correct, here is one of the three calculations I would need to make, just to see if I'm doing this right:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{y}_{1}-\overline{y}_{2}\pm t_{\alpha/2m}\cdot s\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_{2}}} 
&= 81.06-78.56\pm t_{0.05/6}\cdot s_{\text{pooled}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{16}}\\\\
&= 2.5 \pm 2.73\cdot s_{\text{pooled}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{16}} \\\\
&= 2.5 \pm 13.26 \\\\
&= (-10.76, 15.76) \\\\
\end{align*}$$

**Attempt 2**

$$s^2=\frac{(32-1)(17.05^2)+(16-1)(15.43^2)+(16-1)(14.36^2)}{32+16+16-3}\Rightarrow s=16.03$$

$$t_{61, .05/3}=2.46$$

All together,

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{y}_{1}-\overline{y}_{2}\pm t_{61,.05/3}\cdot s\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_{2}}} 
&= 81.06-78.56\pm t_{61,0.05/3}\cdot s\sqrt{\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{16}}\\\\
&= 2.5 \pm 2.46\cdot s\sqrt{\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{16}} \\\\
&= 2.5 \pm 12.074 \\\\
&= (-9.57, 14.57) \\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: There are at least a dozen schemes in use for 'simultaneous CIs'. The idea is to keep 5% error probabilities from each separate comparison (three in your example) from accumulating, so that you can state a confidence level for the 'combined pattern of differences'. Names of few of these schemes are Fisher LSD, Tukey HSD, SNK, Bonferroni, and Duncan. It looks as if you are doing Bonferroni. Also multiple comparisons are generally not used unless an overall test has previously rejected $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3.$ Please clarify what you have done and which method you're using.

Comment: I would like to use Bonferroni. That's what I see in my notes, so I think that would be the one I should use.

Comment: In an example I'm looking at, the s value for each of the differences is the same, which would not be the case if I calculated s in the manner in which I did above.

Comment: It seems you are working under the usual ANOVA assumption that all three groups have the same population variance $\sigma^2.$  In that case, the usual Bonferroni procedure is to find a pooled estimate of $\sigma^2$ from all three groups: $\hat \sigma^2 = [(n_1 - 1)s_1^2 + (n_2 - 1)s_2^2 + (n_3-1)S_3^2]/(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - 3).$ Then the sqrt of that for $s$ in your first displayed eqn., $df = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - 3,$ and if you're working for a 95% overall error rate then use t-value cutting probability $100 - .05/3$ from the upper tail of the appropriate t dist'n.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try to the problem again with this in mind.

Comment: Made a mistake. Re-editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment continued:** With a bit of fussing I made fake normal data to mimic your sample sizes, means, and
standard deviations.

Then did the Bonferroni-adjusted `pairwise.t.test` procedure in R. The output is the three P-values.

It will be interesting
to know whether the R procedure is (as I suspect) the same as the one
you are doing, and whether your P-values match those from the R procedure.

```
mean(ab); sd(ab)
[1] 89.06
[1] 17.05
mean(ne); sd(ne)
[1] 78.56
[1] 15.43
mean(nc); sd(nc)
[1] 87.81
[1] 14.36

y = c(ab, ne, nc)
gp = as.factor(c(rep(1,32), rep(2,16), rep(3,16)))

pairwise.t.test(y, gp, p.adj="bonferroni")

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  y and gp 

  1    2   
  2 0.11 -   
  3 1.00 0.32

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

Thus there are no significant differences among the group means according
to the Bonferroni method. This raises the question whether the main F-test
for the one-way ANOVA rejected $H_0: \mu_{ab} = \mu_{ne} = \mu_{nc}.$ As shown
below it does not, at the 5% level. According to the usual methods of analysis, that failure
to reject would mean that you should not be looking at multiple-comparison
methods.

```
summary(aov(y ~ gp))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
gp           2   1237   618.4   2.406 0.0987 .
Residuals   61  15676   257.0                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Interesting. If each interval contains $0$, that also means there are no significant differences among the group means, correct? Did I calculate the confidence interval correct the second time around?

Comment: Did not check arithmetic, but no obvious errors. Yes, a CI covering 0 does mean no signif difference for that comparison.